# How to prove that Fibonacci number is integer?

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove that formula for Fibonacci numbers are always integers, for all $n$:

$$
F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}
$$
where, $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

I know how to prove that $F_n$ is rational, but what about integer?

Comment: Is induction an option? $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ thereafter (prove those by brute forcing). I know, apparently you want to use the theory of algebraic integers :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Maybe I was a bit unclear, I'm looking of proof with that Golden ratio formula.

Comment: Also, noting that $\sqrt{5} = \varphi - \psi$, you have $$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi - \psi} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \varphi^{n-1-k}\psi^k,$$ so $F_n$ is an algebraic integer. As it's also rational, it must be a rational integer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That should be an answer!

Comment: So was I. Just check that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the roots of $x^2=x+1$, and the recurrence relation follows. Mind you, Daniel's comment is the best answer to this.

Comment: How do you proved that $F_n$ is rational? Binomial theorem?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla That, or shorter, it is conjugation-invariant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{5} = \varphi-\psi$, we have

$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi-\psi} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \varphi^{n-1-k}\psi^k.$$

Since $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are algebraic integers, so is $F_n$. A rational algebraic integer must be a rational integer.